# how to display the two table on one view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

### Model

```
public class aaa
{
   public List<emp> emps { set; get; }
   public List<dept> depts { set; get; }  
}
```

### Action Method

```
public ActionResult detail() 
{ 
   aaa a = new aaa(); 
   a.emps = (from p in db.emps select p).ToList(); 
   a.depts = (from p in db.depts select p).ToList(); 
   return View(a); 
}
```

Comment: this is my controller
`enter code here`

public ActionResult detail()
        {
            aaa a = new aaa();
            a.emps = (from p in db.emps select p).ToList();
            a.depts = (from p in db.depts select p).ToList();
            return View(a);
        }

Comment: You can use either regular table or **[bootstrap table](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables)**. What is your question exactly?

Comment: this is my view@model IEnumerable<data.Models.aaa>
         @{
    ViewBag.Title = "detail";
}<h2>detail</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.emps)
                @Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem=>item.depts)
            </td>
</tr>
    }
    </table>

Comment: this is errorThe model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'data.Models.aaa', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[data.Models.aaa]'

Comment: Put the details of the error in the question, not in comments, and show your view.

Comment: Looks like you had a good answer a few weeks ago, but you have not responded to it despite logging on since it was posted. Please consider responding to people promptly here - we have a lot of people asking for assistance and then ignoring the effort rendered - don't be one of them!

Answer (score 1):

Model inside ***View*** should be `@model data.Models.aaa`.

```
@model data.Models.aaa

<table>
    @foreach (var emp in Model.emps)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@emp.FirstName</td>
        </tr> 
    }
</table>
<table>
    @foreach (var dept in Model.depts)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@dept.Title</td>
        </tr> 
    }
</table>
```